# A modern process for compiling Castle Windsor for Partial Trust

Tags: build, castle-windsor, castle

This issue has been beaten to death on this site and elsewhere. In spite of that, every single thread I've read regarding compiling Castle.Windsor for partial trust (including the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute) has failed.

In the nature of this site, I'd explain what I've tried so far. But that'd just be a (very) long string of links to inapplicable content with no real gain. It's a shame partial trust IoC is treated like such a third-class citizen.

I've downloaded the [Core](https://github.com/castleproject/Core) and [Windsor](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor) projects off github. I'm calling `build.cmd` with a variety of command line arguments as per solutions on SO, Google Groups, and peresonal blogs, forums, et al.

Could someone please provide a *current* method of building Castle.Core and Castle.Windsor with APTCA enabled?

Answer (score 0):

The Castle.Core and Castle.Windsor projects on github already have the `[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]` attribute included in them. Running the included `ClickToBuild.cmd` script in their respective root folders produced a DLL which - verified using ILSpy - does have the attribute.